# How to make audio streaming function faster?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, profiling

I wrote this function, which generates a waveform from the audio data gathered by a microphone, which gets called many times:

```
def generate_waveform(stream, frames_num, waveform):
    # transform stream into numpy array
    data = stream.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)
    waveData = wave.struct.unpack("%dh" % (CHUNK), data)

    npArrayData = np.empty(len(waveData), dtype=np.float32)  # Adjust dtype as needed
    npArrayData = np.asarray(waveData)
    indata = npArrayData

    # update waveform buffer with newer data, flush older data
    waveform_prev = waveform
    waveform[-CHUNK:] = indata
    waveform[:-CHUNK] = waveform_prev[CHUNK:]

    # start and stoppage time for each CHUNK window
    start = chunk_to_seconds(frames_num)
    stop = chunk_to_seconds(frames_num + CHUNK)

    del data, waveData, npArrayData, indata, waveform_prev
    return waveform
```

to be used with

```
CHUNK = int(sr / updates_per_sec)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=sr, input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

for i in range(0,sys.maxsize ** 10):
   generate_waveform(stream, CHUNK * i, waveform)
```

Profiling gives (time unit is milliseconds)

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def generate_waveform(stream, frames_num, waveform):
     2                                               # transform stream into numpy array
     3         1          1.6      1.6     30.5      data = stream.read(CHUNK, exception_on_overflow=False)
     4         1          0.2      0.2      3.5      waveData = wave.struct.unpack("%dh" % (CHUNK), data)
     5         1          0.2      0.2      3.7      npArrayData = np.empty(len(waveData), dtype=np.float32)  # Adjust dtype as needed
     6                                           
     7         1          1.0      1.0     18.8      npArrayData = np.asarray(waveData) ###
     8         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      indata = npArrayData
     9                                           
    10                                               # update waveform buffer with newer data, flush older data
    11         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      waveform_prev = waveform
    12         1          1.2      1.2     23.4      waveform[-CHUNK:] = indata
    13         1          0.9      0.9     18.2      waveform[:-CHUNK] = waveform_prev[CHUNK:]
    14                                           
    15                                               # start and stoppage time for each CHUNK window
    16         1          0.0      0.0      0.9      start = chunk_to_seconds(frames_num)
    17         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      stop = chunk_to_seconds(frames_num + CHUNK)
    18                                           
    19                                           
    20         1          0.1      0.1      1.1      del data, waveData, npArrayData, indata, waveform_prev
    22         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      return waveform
```

Do you know any computational tricks to make it faster?

Comment: Is the audio `waveform` for plotting or for playing?

Comment: It is plotted in real-time.

Comment: You could likely drop the number of samples you are plotting. Also, lines 12 and 13 seem a little wasteful. Array access like that will be slow. Try storing in separate variables. If you already have the data in line 13, you don’t even need it.